# DJANGO Message error when i try to show uploaded file in admin ,in change page

Tags: python, django, admin

In Admin change_page Model when I try to click on the link to display next to the field to display the file already uploaded, it displays the following error

[see image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRw41.jpg)
[when I click in this link to show Pdf file or any file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqJru.jpg)

My Model.py

```
class InstrumentJuridiqueDoc(models.Model): # this model is inline in other model


    cooperationMultilaterale = models.ForeignKey(CooperationMultilaterale, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    cooperationBilaterale = models.ForeignKey(CooperationBilaterale, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    calip = models.ForeignKey(CooperationAvecLesInstitutionsPubliques, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    arj = models.FileField(verbose_name = 'Arabe',blank=True,null=True,
                          help_text='Formats acceptés : PDF, JPG, JPEG, PNG',validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['pdf','JPG', 'JPEG', 'PNG'])])
    frj = models.FileField(verbose_name = 'Français',blank=True,null=True,
                          help_text='Formats acceptés : PDF, JPG, JPEG, PNG',validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['pdf','JPG', 'JPEG', 'PNG'])])
    enj = models.FileField(verbose_name = 'Anglais',blank=True,null=True,
                          help_text='Formats acceptés : PDF, JPG, JPEG, PNG',validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['pdf','JPG', 'JPEG', 'PNG'])])
    esj = models.FileField(verbose_name = 'Espagnol',blank=True,null=True,
                          help_text='Formats acceptés : PDF, JPG, JPEG, PNG',validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['pdf','JPG', 'JPEG', 'PNG'])])
    amj = models.FileField(verbose_name = 'Amazigh',blank=True,null=True,
                          help_text='Formats acceptés : PDF, JPG, JPEG, PNG',validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['pdf','JPG', 'JPEG', 'PNG'])])
    autrej = models.FileField(verbose_name = 'Autre langue',blank=True,
                             null=True,help_text='Formats acceptés : PDF, JPG, JPEG, PNG',validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['pdf','JPG', 'JPEG', 'PNG'])])
```

My url.py Project

```
import django
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin



urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),

    # If no prefix is given, use the default language
    prefix_default_language=True
)
```

how can i solve this ,
other error is when i visite http://127.0.0.1:8000 , i get this error

[frontend error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z5TW.jpg)

for information : now only im working in admin , the frontend is empty,no thing is coded , but i mut see the Django logo  :)

best regards

Comment: You have two different questiosn combined in one question. I would suggest you to post two different questions to get your answer. Btw, I think your url maps `en/` not just `en` (try adding that extra slash)

Comment: thank you for your answer, I thought that maybe the two problems are linked

.does not work, with en/ or without /